# Transform a SQL statement to CRITERIA with UNION

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, union, criteria

I have SQL code that I want to do in criteria (Hibernate) but I'm having trouble with it. My goal is to do this SQL code in Criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM 
             (
              SELECT 'B', D.* 
              FROM table_view1 D 

              UNION 

              SELECT 'S', D.* 
              FROM table_view1 D
              ) 
WHERE dbkey = 1;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please don't [repost questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279384/hibernate-union-in-criteria).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Use native SQL query
- rewrite your query so it is not using union, because Criteria API does not support `UNION`.

Comment: Ok I see.. but in my project i can't use a native SQL QUery .. we must to use Criteria.. so i don't know what can i do .. if you are an other solution for my query

Comment: just curiosity, why you cant use native sql?

Comment: Because I work in a project where we cant use HQL, SQL Native etc .. It is just a standard for this project (don't use HQL, SQL use just CRITERIA )

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use ALIAS for your subquery to access a column belonging to it in outside query WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM 
             (
              SELECT 'B', D.* 
              FROM table_view1 D 

              UNION 

              SELECT 'S', D.* 
              FROM table_view1 D
              ) Z
WHERE Z.dbkey = 1;
```

Comment: Please can you write for me the code in CRITERIA please.. since 4 days I try to do it bbut I can't